# knit2wp adds text with kableExtra

Tags: r, xml, knitr, kableextra

I am trying to post a table to my wordpress site using knit2wp. The table is created using kable and works fine. However, when I use the kableExtra package, and then knit2wp, the following line of text is added to my wordpress site:

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8”?>
```

This line doesn't appear in the html output; only on the website.

I am looking to copy a function as per:

http://dwoll.de/rexrepos/posts/rerWorkflowWP.html

Then integrate the XML function:

```
post.content <- xmlOutputBuffer(header = NULL)
```

Or:

```
post.content <- xmlOutputDOM(xmlDeclaration = NULL)
```

Adding either of these will remove the heading, but also the tables. I am obviously new to XML. So looking for another solution.

**Update:**

Used xml2 to read the html output of knit2html. Then used the following functions:

```
xyz <- read_html("htmloutput.html")
x <- xml_find_all(xyz,".//p")
xml_remove(x, free = TRUE)
```

Saved as new html file, which I then entered into function as per link above.

Comment: I removed the XML declaration in the latest dev version of kableExtra. Thanks for pointing it out! :)